# finding web page source at desired instance VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

IN CODE: At 1 browser clicks a button and takes a time to load. AT 2 i get source code of page in `RichTextBox1`. but as page take time to load code 2 starts before completion of 1 because of that i am unable to get the web page source at desired state? what do i do ? i want to get web page source when web browser completely loads after the execution of code 1.
i have tried

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("some website")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("notification_address").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit") (-----1-----)
    RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText (-----2-----)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DocumentCompleted event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

```
Private Sub DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    ' this is where your code goes RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText (-----2-----)

End Sub
```

Comment: dont work. by using this i get source code at form load

Comment: itll fire multiple times...itll fire after your navigate url data is done...and itll fire after your submit data has reloaded too...youll need to know your state each time for it to work since you have a multi step process